# Append lines which do not contain "|" to the previous line

Tags: text-processing

I have a text file which contains data in the below format.

```
1|0|this is test file line1
2|1|this is test file line2
3|1|this
is
test
file line4
```

Any line that does not contain `|` should be appended to the previous line which contains `|`

**Output:**

```
1|0|this is test file line1
2|1|this is test file line2
3|1|this is test file line4
```

Comment: Ok, but we're not a script-writing service

Answer (score 4):

One way is to use Awk to implement the following algorithm:

- Track the previous line in `prev`
- If the line contains `|`, and it's not the first line, then print `prev`. After that, store the current line in `prev`
- If the line doesn't contain `|`, then append it to `prev`
- At the end of the script, print `prev`

For example like this:

```
awk '/\|/ { if (NR > 1) print prev; prev=$0 }
     !/\|/ { prev = prev $0 }
     END { print prev }' input
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `|` as the field separator: if the line contains a `|` then the `NF` variable will be greater than one.

```
awk -F'|' 'NR > 1 && NF > 1 {print ""} {printf "%s", $0} END {print ""}' file
```

Comment: That's close but does not give the required result.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/\|/ { if (printed==1) print ""; else printed=1;
    printf "%s",$0; next; }; { printf " %s",$0 }; END { print ""; }' inputfile
```

Or, if you don't care about the leading newline, shorter:

```
awk '/\|/ { printf "\n%s",$0; next; }; { printf " %s",$0 }; END { print ""; }' inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Awk is my go-to utility for text manipulation:

```
awk '/\|/ && NR>1 { printf "\n" } !/\|/ && NR>1 { printf " " } { printf $0 } END { printf "\n" }' file
```

1. Print a newline character if the line contains `|` (but not for the first line):
   `/\|/ && NR>1 { printf "\n" }`
2. Otherwise, print a space (but not for the first line):
   `!/\|/ && NR>1 { printf " " }`
3. Print the entire line, *without* a trailing newline character:
   `{ printf $0 }`
4. Print a newline at the end of the file:
   `END { printf "\n" }`

Answer (score 0):

One more awk:

```
awk -F'|' 'NR>1{printf prev (NF>1?"\n":" ")}{prev=$0}END{print prev}' file
```

Testing

```
$ cat file1
1|1|this is test file line1
2|2|this is test file line2
3|3|this
is
test
file line3
4|4|this is test file line4
5|5|this is
test file
line5
6|6|this is test file line6

$ awk -F'|' 'NR>1{printf prev (NF>1?"\n":" ")}{prev=$0}END{print prev}' file1
1|1|this is test file line1
2|2|this is test file line2
3|3|this is test file line3
4|4|this is test file line4
5|5|this is test file line5
6|6|this is test file line6
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using Perl:

```
perl -e '$f=1;while(<>){chomp;print(($f?"":/\|/?"\n":" ").$_);$f=0}'
```

Alternatively, you can use this sed script:

```
sed -E ':s;N;s/\n([^\n|]*)$/ \1/;bs'
```

It is a loop that

- `N` reads a line and appends it to the pattern space
- `s/\n([^\n|]*)$/ \1/` if the line in the pattern space does not contain `|`, replace the newline with a space
- `bs` jump back to the `:s` label